# if $|f(x)|\leq M_0$ and $|f''(x)\leq M_2$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$ then $|f'(x)|\leq M_1$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$

Tags: inequality

I tried to prove that if $f\in C^2[0,\infty)$ and there exist two positive numbers $M_0$ and $M_2$ such that for all $x\in [0,\infty)$, $|f(x)|\leq M_0$ and $|f''(x)|\leq M_2$ then there exists $M_1\in [0,\infty)$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq M_1.$

If $f\in C^2[0,b]$ then I can prove it using the Taylor expension of $f$ i.e. for $a\in [0,b]$, $$ 
\begin{align}
\exists x_0 \in [0,b],\;\; \ f(0) &= f(a) -af'(a) + \frac{1}{2}a^2f''(x_0) \\
 \exists x_1 \in [0,b],\;\;f(b) &= f(a) +(b-a)f'(a) + \frac{1}{2}(b-a)^2f''(x_1)
\end{align}.$$ From that, $$f'(a) = \frac{f(b) - f(0)}{b} + \frac{1}{4}[a^2f’’(x_0) - (b-a)^2f’’(x_1)].$$ It follows that $|f'(a)|\leq M_1$
for some $M_1$.

Is it possible to extend that proof so that we will have the same result for $f\in C^2[0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Extended MVT](http://www.nabla.hr/CL-DerivativeG1.htm), also known as [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), there exists a number $\xi \in (x,x+1)$ such that

$$f(x+1)=f(x)+f'(x)+\frac12 f''(\xi)$$

Solving for $f'(x)$, we find that

$$|f'(x)|=|f(x+1)-f(x)-\frac12 f''(\xi)|\le 2M_0+\frac12M_2=M_1$$

And we are done!

Comment: How did you get that please? I get from the MVT that $\exists \zeta \in (x,x+1)$ such that $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\zeta)$

Comment: This is the extended MVT (or Taylor's Theorem).